# --fix doesn't fix the errors using eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, editor, eslint

I'm using eslint in visual code to format the js files but it gives me errors everytime i run it, here's my command line to run it
`node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint -- src --fix` the error message

```
E:\PATH\src\reducers\roote-reducer.js
  1:8   error  There should be no space after '{'                object-curly-spacing
  1:26  error  There should be no space before '}'               object-curly-spacing
  6:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces  indent
  7:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces  indent
  8:4   error  Newline required at end of file but not found     eol-last

E:\PATH\src\reducers\schedule-reducer.js
   1:8   error  There should be no space after '{'                  object-curly-spacing
   1:22  error  There should be no space before '}'                 object-curly-spacing
   4:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 4 spaces    indent
   7:24  error  Missing space before function parentheses           space-before-function-paren
   7:54  error  Missing space before opening brace                  space-before-blocks
   8:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 4 spaces    indent
   9:1   error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 4 spaces    indent

E:\PATH\src\register-service-worker.js
   12:1  error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces    indent
   17:1  error  Expected indentation of 5 tabs but found 6 spaces   indent
   17:7  error  Use regex shorthands to improve readability         unicorn/regex-shorthand
   22:1  error  Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 2 spaces    indent

✖ 309 problems (309 errors, 0 warnings)
  309 errors, 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

How can i fix them automatically?

Comment: Note that not all errors/warnings are fixable by `--fix`

Comment: How can to fix this errors/warnings?

Answer (score 67):

To use `--fix` option, you need to run eslint directly.

Try this

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --fix
```

On Windows:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\eslint src\** --fix
```

Comment: it doesn't work correctly, it give just one error (the first error), and didn't solve it!

Comment: Edited, can you tell more about the issue?

Comment: Please try to explain your solution a bit so that people can understand why the issue occurs and what the actual problem & solution is.

Comment: This worked for me after I specified a directory as the last argument, after `--fix`, eg: `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix myJsFiles/`. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to run binaries directly from `./node_modules/.bin`. This is what `npx` and `npm exec` are for.

Comment: And if you are a lover of **yarn**, use `yarn eslint src --fix`. Thank me later!

Answer (score 15):

The format should be:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix path/to/file.js
```

See [this thread](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10192) (and aravind1078's answer) for more background.

Comment: I used     ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix src/**.* to run on all files inside /src

Answer (score 11):

Run the below command in the new terminal:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix . --ext .js,.vue src`

Answer (score 9):

in the directory in which you code exists run :

```
eslint --fix .
```

instead of

```
eslint --fix
```

as the command needs an argument which indicates the directory in which the code exists or the file itself you want to apply linting on

Comment: I had to specify the file(s) explicitly, e.g. `eslint --fix src/path/some.js`. The above didn't scan the directories for files.

Answer (score 7):

**Try to run**

```
eslint --fix
```

you have to install first eslint

```
npm install -g eslint
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem as well. Run into this and tried to debug for almost 1 hr

Comment: Hero! Might I add using the `.` at the end. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

Use Command-Line Terminal, to run the below commands in Visual Studio Code.

Make sure .eslintrc.yml file configured for the working project

To fix lint issues in a file

```
npx eslint file1.js --fix
```

To fix lint issues in all the files in the folder

```
npx eslint ./folder_name --fix
```

Comment: For some reason this was the only solution that worked for me... thanks so much!

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

- I had difficulties in using `--fix` when I use **eslint-config-airbnb-base** instead of **@nuxtjs/eslint-module** in Nuxt.js project
- At that time running eslint direclty worked for me:
  `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix`

However, my preferred one is to write two more scripts into **package.json**

```
"lint": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
"lint-fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
```

And run `yarn lint-fix` or `npm run lint-fix`

Answer (score 3):

First install eslint if you already haven't

```
npm install -g eslint
```

Then run

```
eslint --fix path/to/file.extension
```

> Note: You will have to run the the above command every time after making changes to that particular file.

Answer (score 2):

If it didn't

```js
extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          options: {
            fix: true
          }
        })
      }
    }
You. You can use this on the first page
    const colors = require('vuetify/es5/util/colors').default
    const pkg = require('./package')
    require('dotenv').config()

    module.exports = {
      mode: 'universal',
      /*
      ** Headers of the page
      */
      head: {
        titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
        title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
        meta: [
          { charset: 'utf-8' },
          { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
          }
        ],
        link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
      },
      /*
      ** Customize the progress-bar color
      */
      loading: { color: '#fff' },
      /*
      ** Global CSS
      */
      css: [],
      /*
      ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
      */
      plugins: [],
      /*
      ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
      */
      buildModules: [
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
      ],
      /*
      ** Nuxt.js modules
      */
      modules: [
        // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module
        '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
      ],
      /*
      ** Axios module configuration
      ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
      */
      axios: {},
      /*
      ** vuetify module configuration
      ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
      */
      /*
      ** Build configuration
      */
      build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {
          // Run ESLint on save
          if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
              enforce: 'pre',
              test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
              loader: 'eslint-loader',
              exclude: /(node_modules)/,
              options: {
                fix: true
              }
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

> [If you still don't understand me.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTEAWpJ-vpA&list=PLe30vg_FG4OQihO5an0tNT_dpkxig8iPz&index=7)

Comment: This fixed the issue in my Nuxt Project, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem I run

```
eslint --fix fileName.extention
```

Answer (score 1):

First Install Package:
npm install -g eslint

and

Run:
eslint --fix

Answer (score 1):

if it doesn't fix any error with the '--fix' flag, it means your ESlint config file has an error. please cross check the file again

Answer (score 0):

Run the terminal and run this code to see all the of your error. It can help you to fixed the error.

`npx eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx --cache --cache-strategy content --quiet`

Answer (score 0):

For future people, if the terminal shows these lint rules fixable by `--fix` and you have tried to run `npx eslint . --fix` but not working as expected. Maybe you have a conflict configuration in Prettier. Prettier takes precedence over eslint.

In my case, I have the below config in my `.prettierrc.js`

```
  jsxBracketSameLine: true
```

And I have the below rule in my `.eslintrc.js`

```
'react/jsx-closing-bracket-location': [2, 'line-aligned']
```

Eslint definitely can fix my issue automatically once I set  `jsxBracketSameLine: false` or remove it in `.prettierrc.js`
[image]